# Check if the time is within the last five minutes

Tags: javascript

I have a time displayed on my webpage, and im trying to do an action if the time value i have is 5 minutes or older than the current time.

```
var date1   = new Date(1625807904*1000); // 1625807904 is my date and time

var convert = date1.getDate()+"/"+(date1.getMonth()+1)+"/"+date1.getFullYear()+"  "+date1.getHours()+ ":"+ (date1.getMinutes()<10?'0':'') + date1.getMinutes()+ ":"+(date1.getSeconds()<10?'0':'')+date1.getSeconds();
```

Just my concept

```
if ( convert < 5minutes or older than the current time){

**** do something ****

}
```

Thank you for your time !!!

Comment: What is `Date1`?

Comment: You could compare in milliseconds.  Within the last 5 minutes would be `>= Date.now() - (5 * 60 * 1000)`

Comment: Use this  "https://momentjs.com/" to easily perform operation using date and time

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi sorry it was a typo. Fixed it!

Comment: I think you don't need `convert ` simple subtract two dates and convert to minutes and check your conditions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can subtract two `Date` in JavaScript. The default value is based on millisecond:

```js
var date   = new Date(1625807904*1000);

console.log('diffrences based on milliseconds', Date.now() - date)
console.log('diffrences based on minutes',  (Date.now() - date) /(60 * 1000))

if((Date.now() - date) <= (5 * 60 * 1000))
{
    console.log("your condition is meeted. Do your ACTION")
}
```

Comment: when i do
 if((Date.now() - date) /(60 * 1000) >5)  it works perfectly. So  shouldnt it be >5 ?

Comment: Yes they are the same

Comment: in my case I need to add getTime() to date: `if((Date.now() - date.getTime()) <= (5 * 60 * 1000))`